# Maven PMD Plugin 3.5 fails with JDK13

Tags: maven, pmd

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.5:pmd (pmd) on project my_project: Execution pmd of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.5:pmd failed: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Unsupported targetJdk value '13'. -> [Help 1]
```

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version (3.13.0) that ships with a version of PMD that supports Java 13.

Comment: Same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61417986/pmd-plugin-fails-with-java-14-unsupported-targetjdk
Updated pmd version - I used the latest - it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to update the maven-pmd-plugin. Version 3.5 is already 5 years old...

Current (2020-04-25) latest released version is 3.13.0, which supports Java 13 out of the box (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPMD-295 for the original issue).

More info on maven-pmd-plugin:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/

If you want to update PMD (e.g. to support Java 14), you'll need to override the plugin's dependencies as described here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/upgrading-PMD-at-runtime.html and use a version of PMD, that supports Java 14 (PMD 6.22.0+).